# SQL Server Management Studio Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a problem while connecting to a SQL Server through Management Studio.

After trying to connect with my credentials, I get the following error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MLCn.png)

When I try to connect through Visual Studio everything works fine! I logon with a SQL Login which has administrator privileges.

Thanks for any help and best regards

Michael

Comment: Care to translate that dialog to English for us poor schleps who can't speak your otherwise beautiful German tongue?

Comment: @RachelAmbler: *Error connecting to 'SQL01'* - Additional Information: The method "get_TargetDatabaseEngineEdition" in type ".....ScriptingOptions" in assembly "....." has no implementation (mscorlib)

Comment: What version of sql server are you connecting to? Sounds like it might be an older version?

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. There's a post on MSDN where someone had the same error connecting to Sql Express. Are you attempting to connect to Sql Express or a full blown SKU of Sql Server? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/aaa7ccb8-021e-4e1c-89e1-2ffeaec41a14/error-connecting-to-localsqlexpress?forum=TFService

Comment: @RachelAmbler ups sorry for that one! I think it's not the express version (not shure how to check this)

Comment: @SqlACID I'm runnin SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: after the 3rd reinstall of SSMS the problem didn't occure anymore, may was a problem with the source! (worked after new download)

Anyway, thanks for your help and time!

Cheers Michael